# For all rank two tensors, is $A:BC = AB^T:C$?

Tags: matrices, tensors, tensor-rank

Suppose that $A$, $B$, $C$ are rank two tensors that are not necessarily symmetric, and I have a contraction as below. Is the following equivalent?

$A:BC \equiv AB^T:C$

If not, what is the correct expression that will have only C on the right side? Thanks

Comment: What may I have done wrong, please, anyone?

Comment: If you define the contraction as $A:BC={\rm tr}(A^TBC)$, then the rules for rearranging the terms follow from the properties of the trace  $$\eqalign{A:BC&=AC^T:B\cr&=B^TA:C\cr&=BC:A\cr&=A^T:(BC)^T}$$

Comment: Hi @lynn you should write this as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Frobenius (aka double-dot) product of two matrices can be written in terms of the trace 
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
The properties of the trace give rise to various rules for rearranging terms within the product. 
For example 
$$\eqalign{
A:BC
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= B^TA:C \cr
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
}$$